Troubleshooting Dynamic Distribution Group Filters: Excluding Disabled Objects
I’m currently working on creating a RecipientFilter for my test dynamic distribution group (on-premise), which I plan to replicate for a new group in my production environment. However, I’ve encountered a challenge that I’m hoping you can help me solve.
Here is the current filter I’m using:
-RecipientFilter {((Title -like '*X') -or (Title -like 'X*')) -and  (Company -like 'X*') -and (Y)}

I want to replace "Y" with a condition that excludes disabled objects. When I run a Format-List on a user, I see the property isValid, but when I attempt to use it in the filter, I receive the following error:
Cannot bind parameter 'RecipientFilter' to the target. Exception setting "RecipientFilter": ""isValid" is not a recognized filterable property.

I’ve tried various syntax adjustments, but haven’t been able to find a direct solution, only a workaround. Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

You can find the valid attributes for filtering here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/recipientfilter-properties?view=exchange-ps - there is no isValid, perhaps you could use IsMailboxEnabled -eq $true

Thank you for your response.
When using IsMailboxEnabled, disabled objects are not being filtered unfortunately.

I see that the attribute "ExchangeUserAccountControl" is available, which I can use for this challenge. When an account is disabled, the value changes to: "0x202" where by the active objects the value is '0x200'.
However, when trying to use the HEX, I get the following error:
Cannot bind parameter 'RecipientFilter' to the target. Exception setting "RecipientFilter": "The value "0x202" could not be converted to type Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.Recipient.UserAccountControlFlags."
I also get an error when using the value without ' ' and when using it as a hex: [char]0x02
